# SSRS 2016 Sporatic Error rrRenderingError

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS 2016 Report. When I run the report by clicking the report in the SSRS Site it runs fine. When I use the url to create the pdf like this:

http://vmbksa69901mdt/ReportServer_ssrs1p?/DAS/CDO_Suite/PortfolioHoldings&rs:Command=Render&ReportName=OCTAGO28_Portfolio_Holdings_pdf_1&rs:Format=PDF

It gives me the error:

> The webpage at
>   http://vmbksa69901mdt/ReportServer_ssrs1p?/DAS/CDO_Suite/PortfolioHoldings&rs:Command=Render&ReportName=OCTAGO28_Portfolio_Holdings_pdf_1&rs:Format=PDF
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

When I look at the view [dbo].[ExecutionLog3], it shows an error of rrRenderingError.

What's odd is that if I change the url and put the "format=Excel", it works fine. And then right away change it back to PDF it works fine.

So my guess is this is a timeout issue. Can anyone tell if that is a valid assumption? If it is, how do I go about changing that timeout? The underlying stored procedure for the report can take > 60s.

If it's not a timeout, how do I dig deeper into the logs to show me what the error really could be?

Comment: depending on your setup there may be several areas that could timeout. It sounds like you are using a shared dataset though as this might explain why it works on subsequent runs. Check this link, it might be useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/setting-time-out-values-for-report-and-shared-dataset-processing-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi Alan- thanks for taking the time to look at this. It's taken me awhile to get back to this problem. But I've exhausted this as a timeout issue, as the error comes up right away. And the execution log is showing this as a rendering error. So are there logs that would show me more detailed logging?

Comment: I found what was causing my issue. I had an expression on the report that was causing it, once i took that off all reports were fine. It was very odd, as I had 135 instances of the report being scheduled and 100 worked fine, the other 35 would fail. The only difference was each schedule ran with unique parms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: Turns out that it was an expression on my report:

```
="Portfolio Holdings Report as of " & Format(CDate(First(Fields!ReportParameterValue.Value, "AsOfDate")), "MM/d/yy")
```

When I took this off, the report ran fine. However I still needed this on my report, so I made a hidden parm, and set a default value from my AsOfDate Dataset. Then made the expression this:

```
="Portfolio Holdings Report as of " & Format(CDate(Parameters!AsOfDate.Value), "MM/d/yy")
```

Then all of my scheduled events went off without a hitch.